# firebase angularfire create forum styled app using dyanmic url

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create a firebase forum styled app where , users can create group using string ,
the idea is dynamically create a firebase url ,based on the string value passed from the in and load the messages from that url.

This is my factory

```
.factory('gossipDetailService', function($firebaseArray) {
return {
    loadDetail: function(node) {
        console.log(typeof node);

        var ref = new Firebase("http://porteyapptest.firebaseio.com/gossip/" + node);

        return $firebaseArray(ref);
    }
};
```

});

This is my controller

```
controller('gossipDetCtrl', function ($scope,gossipDetailService,$cordovaCamera,$ionicModal,$stateParams) {
console.log($stateParams.id);
$scope.messages = gossipDetailService.loadDetail($stateParams.id).$loaded(
    console.log("loadDetail")
);

$scope.addMessage = function() {
    console.log("adding message");
    $scope.message.timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    $scope.messages.$add($scope.message);
    $scope.message.content = "";
};
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Fire base allows you to create synchronised arrays.

For Eg.`$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('messages'))`
Where Ref would be your .firebase.io (dashboard url)'s object.

Now you can read the data from messages and display the content in that child or push values into messages and display them.

Please read the doc once.

[Angularfire doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)